# finding an xpath of a link with a td contains text

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, codeception

hitting a wall when trying to find a working xpath for this block of code
i have tried

```
//a[contains(text(),'SmartTrak')]//a[2] ->doesnt work
//td[contains(text(),'123123123')]//a[2] ->doesnt work
//td[contains(text(),'123123123')]/following::a ->clicks on the wrong link
```

I am trying to click the SmartTrak link associated with "123123123"
any help is appreciated!

```
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">123123123</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="right" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">.99</td>
<input id="bp_0" type="hidden" value="N" name="bp_0">
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">Mail</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="right" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">0.00</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="left" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">INVOICE</td>
<td class="BlackSmall" align="center" style="white-space: nowrap">
<a class="hovsml" target="_blank" href="/retrievethis.php?c=hdhdhddhd=dsdsdsddds">ViewPDF</a>
<span style="width:20px; display:inline-block;"></span>
<a class="HovSml" href="JavaScript: INVDetails(xxxx)">SmartTrak</a>
```

Comment: HTML source is not correct or complete. Can you edit with parent `<tr>`s and/or closing `</td>`s?

Comment: <div id="scrollableDocumentsTable" onscroll="onScrollHideFilters();">
<table id="documentsTable" width="960" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#008677">
<tr height="19" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td align="center">

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one go with a single XPath expression:

```
//td[. = '123123123']/following-sibling::td/a[. = 'SmartTrak']
```

Here we are locating the `td` element with `123123123` text, getting the following `td` sibling element having an `a` element with `SmartTrak` text as a direct child.

Comment: perfect, thank you for the explanation, works perfectly!